On my React Native app, why did the privacy manifests on my installed Pods disappear?
Working with an existing React Native 0.73.6 iOS app, I performed a directory search on the Pods directory and found several PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy files that had been added by the install process.
As a control test, I deleted my node_modules and Pods directories and reinstalled all files.
Now the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy files have disappeared. They no longer exist in the Pods directory?
Where did they go?
